# react redux using useSelector multiple times in app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Hello I am using a selector multiple times in my Application.
Can I write the code once and import then the selector?
I thought to write a custom hook but I think this it is not necessary.
Here is my Selector:

```
const county = useSelector((state)=>{
    const id = state.user.id
    const name = state.user.name
    return state.users.filter((user) => user.name === name)[0].county
})
```

It would nice if I have something like this:

```
import {countySelector} from 'selectors'
const county = useSelector(countySelector)
```

Comment: What a problem? Redux has built in useSelector hook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass arrow function in `useSelector`

```
export const countySelector = state => {
    const id = state.user.id;
    const name = state.user.name;
    return state.users.find(user => user.name === name).county;
};

// Usage
import { countySelector } from 'selectors';
const county = useSelector(countySelector);
```

Or create custom hook

```
const useCounty = () => {
    return useSelector(state => {
        const id = state.user.id;
        const name = state.user.name;
        return state.users.find(user => user.name === name).county;
    });
};

export default useCounty;

// Usage
import useCounty from 'useCounty';
const county = useCounty();
```

Comment: Just replace the filter with `.find` so that you don't get the first index of the result.

Comment: You can improve reusability if you use reselect, it comes with redux toolkit and is part of the [standard template](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#create-a-react-redux-app) when creating new redux applications.

Answer (score 3):

Standard redux [template](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#create-a-react-redux-app) comes with redux toolkit and that comes with [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect). [Here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) are some examples of how to create composable memoized selectors.